# Decrypting a Chacha20-Poly1305 string without using tag\mac

Tags: javascript, python, encryption, cryptography, libsodium

I am able to successfully encrypt and decrypt a string using Chacha20-Poly1305 in python without using the tag (or mac) as follows (using pycryptodome library):

```
from Crypto.Cipher import ChaCha20_Poly1305

key = '20d821e770a6d3e4fc171fd3a437c7841d58463cb1bc7f7cce6b4225ae1dd900' #random generated key
nonce = '18c02beda4f8b22aa782444a' #random generated nonce

def decode(ciphertext):
    cipher = ChaCha20_Poly1305.new(key=bytes.fromhex(key), nonce=bytes.fromhex(nonce))
    plaintext = cipher.decrypt(bytes.fromhex(ciphertext))
    return plaintext.decode('utf-8')


def encode(plaintext):
    cipher = ChaCha20_Poly1305.new(key=bytes.fromhex(key), nonce=bytes.fromhex(nonce))
    ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(plaintext.encode('utf-8'))
    return ciphertext.hex()

encrypted = encode('abcdefg123')
print(encrypted)

# will print: ab6cf9f9e0cf73833194

print(decode(encrypted))

# will print: abcdefg123
```

However, taking this to Javascript, I cannot find a library that will decrypt this without requiring the mac (that I would have gotten if I had used encrypt_and_digest()).

I tried virtually every library I could find (Npm, as this would be used in a React application), they all require the mac part for the decryption.
for example: libsodium-wrappers, js-chacha20 etc.

How can I overcome this?

P.S.
I know it is less safe to not use the mac part, this is for educational purposes.

=== EDIT ===

1. The string was encrypted with Chacha20-Poly1305 and its encrypted output is already given. It cannot be re-encrypted using a different algorithm.
2. I cannot encrypt using Chacha20-Poly1305 and decrypt with Chacha20 or vice versa because encrypting with the same key and nonce using only Chacha20 (rather than Chacha20-Poly1305) gives me a different encrypted output and this it is not helping.

Comment: "Chacha20-Poly1305 without the tag" is just ChaCha20.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo The string was encrypted with Chacha20-Poly1305 and its output is already given. Encrypting with the same key and nonce using only Chacha20 gives me a different encrypted output.

Comment: Then use ChaCha20 on both sides. If you don't care about the MAC (which is very dubious) then you don't need the Poly1305 part.

Comment: Hi, I can't because the data is already encrypted with Chacha20-Poly1305.
think of it like I have a list of encrypted strings, a key and a nonce. I don't have the tags \macs and I can't get them.
I am able to decrypt all of them in python without using the tags, my question is how can I do it in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused by different values for the initial counter regarding encryption/decryption in the libraries applied.

Background: ChaCha20 is operated in counter mode to derive a key stream that is XORed with the plaintext. Thereby an (increment-by-one) counter counts through a sequence of input blocks for the [ChaCha20 block function](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8439#section-2.3). The initial counter is the start value of that counter. For more details on ChaCha20, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/70117) and [RFC 8439](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8439).

---

A similar situation regarding different initial counters can be found in the *PyCryptodome* library itself:

With ChaCha20-Poly1305, the counter 0 is used to determine the authentication tag, so the counter 1 is the first value applied for encryption, s. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChaCha20-Poly1305#Description).

*PyCryptodome* follows this logic within the [`ChaCha20_Poly1305`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/chacha20_poly1305.html) implementation for `encrypt()` as well, to ensure that `encrypt()` and `digest()` give the same result as `encrypt_and_digest()`.
However, within the [`ChaCha20`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/chacha20.html) implementation, the initial counter for encryption is 0 by default (and not 1).

Therefore, to allow decryption of the ciphertext generated with `ChaCha20_Poly1305#encrypt()` using `ChaCha205#decrypt()`, the counter must be explicitly set to 1 for the latter.
This can be achieved with the `seek()` method (note that `seek()` requires the position in bytes; since a ChaCha20 block is 64 bytes in size, the counter value 1 corresponds to byte index 64 in the key stream):

```py
from Crypto.Cipher import ChaCha20, ChaCha20_Poly1305

key = '20d821e770a6d3e4fc171fd3a437c7841d58463cb1bc7f7cce6b4225ae1dd900' # 32 bytes key
nonce = '18c02beda4f8b22aa782444a' # 12 bytes nonce
plaintext = 'abcdefg123'

# Encrypt with ChaCha20_Poly1305#encrypt()
cipher = ChaCha20_Poly1305.new(key=bytes.fromhex(key), nonce=bytes.fromhex(nonce))
ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(plaintext.encode('utf-8'))
print(ciphertext.hex()) # ab6cf9f9e0cf73833194

# Decrypt with ChaCha20#decrypt()
decipher = ChaCha20.new(key=bytes.fromhex(key), nonce=bytes.fromhex(nonce))  
decipher.seek(64) # set counter to 1 (seek() requires the position in bytes, a ChaCha20 block is 64 bytes)
decrypted = decipher.decrypt(ciphertext)  
print(decrypted.decode('utf-8')) # ab6cf9f9e0cf73833194
```

---

The same applies to *js-chacha20*, a ChaCha20 implementation for JavaScript. By default, 0 is applied as the initial counter for encryption, s. [here](https://github.com/thesimj/js-chacha20/blob/master/src/jschacha20.js#L68). Thus, to be compatible with ciphertexts created with *PyCryptodome*'s `ChaCha20_Poly1305#encrypt()`, the initial counter must be explicitly set to 1:

```js
const key = hex2ab("20d821e770a6d3e4fc171fd3a437c7841d58463cb1bc7f7cce6b4225ae1dd900"); // 32 bytes key
const nonce = hex2ab("18c02beda4f8b22aa782444a"); // 12 bytes nonce
const ciphertext = hex2ab("ab6cf9f9e0cf73833194"); // ciphertext from PyCryptodome

const decryptor = new JSChaCha20(key, nonce, 1); // Fix: set initial counter = 1 in the 3rd parameter
const plaintext = decryptor.decrypt(ciphertext);
console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(plaintext)); // abcdefg123

function hex2ab(hex){
    return new Uint8Array(hex.match(/[\da-f]{2}/gi).map(function (h) {return parseInt(h, 16)}));
}
```

```html
<script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-chacha20@1.1.0/src/jschacha20.min.js "></script>
```

With this change, the ciphertext is decrypted correctly.

---

For completeness: The ChaCha20 specification allows *any* value for the initial counter and explicitly lists the values 1 (e.g. in the context of an AEAD algorithm) and 0 as the usual values.
In chapter *[2.4. The ChaCha20 Encryption Algorithm](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8439#section-2.4)* of *RFC 8439, ChaCha20 and Poly1305 for IETF Protocols* it states regarding the counter:

> A 32-bit initial counter. This can be set to any number, but will
> usually be zero or one. It makes sense to use one if we use the
> zero block for something else, such as generating a one-time
> authenticator key as part of an AEAD algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated response! This certainly makes sense. When coming to implement it in React though I get this error:
TypeError: js_chacha20__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.JSChaCha20 is not a constructor

I already installed js-chacha20 using npm and added it to my package.json.
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @ylu - Unfortunately I can't reproduce this problem in my local environment and also online with React, see here https://playcode.io/1641201. Since this is a different problem, you should ask a new question about this on SO with exact details about your environment and all the info needed to answer.

Comment: [Note that RFC 7530 make free to choose 1 or 0 for chahca20](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/108429/decrypting-a-chacha20-poly1305-string-without-using-tag-mac#comment232197_108429)